# Rules for Commiting code on SVN with Multiples Developers

Tags: iphone, ios, svn, project

We are working on a single project, and also committing code at the end of day on SVN so that can get all update project. But issues is very often our code getting errors while committing code and projects get empty if someone get update at that time. So my question is are there any set of rules which we've to follow on committing so that every one go on straight path and no one get in trouble and save a lot time from these errors.
Thanks in advance. Cheers

Comment: Commit code as you finish things, not just once a day.

Comment: If you are using Mac for development; Consider using GIT. It's built in and easy to use.

Comment: @Viral totally agreed to you. GIT is much much better then SVN.

Comment: "But issues is very often our code getting errors while committing code and projects get empty if someone get update at that time" -- I don't understand what this means.  What errors are you seeing?  What do you mean by "projects get empty"?  What practices do you have in place?

Answer (score 3):

Search Google, something similar to "source control best practices".

[Top result](http://homes.cs.washington.edu/~mernst/advice/version-control.html#incorporate-frequently) has several tips.  Sounds like the biggest problem you're facing is integrating with others' changes.  Perhaps look into the following sections:

*Incorporate others' changes frequently*

*Share your changes frequently*

*Coordinate with your co-workers*

Answer (score 2):

Investigate why you get errors. Blind application of rules is not good.

For example:

- person A committed a code producing compilation error
- why?
- he finished his task, but hasn't checked build before committing to the trunk
- why?
- the entire build it too slow
- solution: speed-up build, set up continuous build system which will check every commit and notify developers about problems as soon as possible

Another example:

- person B committed a code which breaks the build
- why?
- he wanted to store his changes, but the task is not finished
- solution: advice him to create a branch, when the task is finished it can be merged to the trunk (if branch lives for long time, merge changes from trunk to it periodically, then the merge will not be a problem)

There possible other scenarios. With more details you will be able to ask more precise question on StackOverflow and get better answers.

Answer (score 0):

1. In case of use of SVN co-ordination is must between the team.
2. Make sure whenever you commit the code you have a idea about what are you committing.
3. The golden rule is "One developer One class".
4. If at all two different developers are working on same class. Ask them to maintain a document on what changes they have made. And, most important to mark a comments in a class it self.
5. There are some important things which need to be followed while committing the code. Whenever you see a conflict in your local files and server files. Make sure you go through every conflict and select the appropriate action.
6. Understand one important thing, whenever SVN is used one persons mistake can affect everyone.

Comment: I don't agree with Rule#3, only because it just make using SVN/GIT meaningless. Personal opinion, though.

Answer (score 0):

- Whenever possible, don't edit the same line of code as someone else
- Leave meaningful comments on your commit messages
- Comment your code
- Make sure that all the code you commit compiles and runs as it should
- Commit when appropriate ie: are passing off part of your code to be used by others or are done working on a feature
- Make sure to communicate with other team members
- If you find code that you don't know what it does, ask the author
- If you're making major changes that will take a while to implement, use a branch and then merge it back in